# R - Spatstat - Nearest neighbour searching by ID using data table

Tags: r, data.table, spatstat

I have two large dataframes called `intersections` (representing intersections of a street system) and `users` (representing users of a network) as follows:

`intersections` has three columns: `x`,`y` and `label_street`. They respectively represent the position of an intersection in a squared observation window (say [0,5] x [0,5]) and the street it is located on. Here is an example:

```
intersections <- data.frame(x=c(0.147674, 0.235356, 0.095337, 0.147674), y=c(0.132956, 0.150813, 0.087345, 0.132956), label_street = c(5,6,5,6))

head(intersections)

            x        y label_street
1    0.147674 0.132956            5
2    0.235356 0.150813            6
3    0.095337 0.087345            5
4    0.147674 0.132956            6
```

An intersection being located at the crossing of several streets, every `(x,y)` combination in the `intersections` table appears at least twice, but with different `label_street` (e.g. rows 1 and 4 in the previous example). The `label_street` may not be the row number (which is why it starts at 5 in my example).

`users` has 4 columns: `x`,`y`, `label_street`, `ID`. They respectively represent the position of a user, the street it is located on and a unique `ID` per user. There are no duplicates in this dataframe, as a user is located on a unique street and has a unique `ID`. Here is an example (the `ID` and the `label_street` may not be the row number)

```
users <- data.frame(x = c(0.20428152, 0.17840619, 0.12964668, 0.20423856, 0.19349761, 0.10861251), y = c(0.14448448, 0.13921481, 0.11724543, 0.14447573, 0.14228827, 0.09891443), label_street = c(6,6,5,6,6,5), ID = c(2703, 3460, 4325, 12506, 19753, 21282))


head(users)
              x          y label_street      ID
1    0.20428152 0.14448448            6    2703
2    0.17840619 0.13921481            6    3460
3    0.12964668 0.11724543            5    4325
4    0.20423856 0.14447573            6   12506
5    0.19349761 0.14228827            6   19753
6    0.10861251 0.09891443            5   21282
```

What I want to do is the following: for each point `(x,y)` of `intersections`, get the `ID` and the distance to its closest neighbour **sharing the same** `street_label` in `users`

I have a working solution using `spatstat` function `nncross` for nearest neighbour searching and `plyr` function `adply` for working on the data.

My working solution is as follows:

1) Write a user-defined function which gets the ID and the distance to the nearest neighbour of a row in a query table

```
 NN <- function(row,query){
 df <- row
 window <- c(0,5,0,5)   #Need this to convert to ppp objects and compute NN distance using nncross
 NN <- nncross(as.ppp(row[,1:2],window),as.ppp(query[,1:2],window))
 df$NN.ID <- query$ID[NN$which]
 df$dist <- NN$dist
 return(df)
}
```

2) Apply this user-defined function row-wise to my dataframe "intersections" with the query being the subset of users sharing the same street_label as the row :

```
result <- adply(intersections, 1, function(row) NN(row, users[users$label_street == row$label_street, ])
```

The result is as follows on the example:

```
head(result)
           x           y    label_street     NN.ID         NN.dist
1   0.147674    0.132956               5      4325      0.02391247
2   0.235356    0.150813               6      2703      0.03171236
3   0.095337    0.087345               5     21282      0.01760940
4   0.147674    0.132956               6      3460      0.03136304
```

Since my real dataframes will be huge, I think computing distance matrices for looking at the nearest neighbour won't be efficient and that `adply` will be slow. 
Does anyone have an idea of a `data.table` like solution? I only now about the basics of `data.table` and have always found it very efficient compared to `plyr`.

Comment: I would use the package `RANN`, finding nearest neighbours in O(N * log(N)) time (i.e., fast), use a loop over the different levels of `label_street`, calling `RANN::nn2` for each level (only selecting rows with these corresponding levels in users and intersect). In `RANN::nn2` you can define the data and query (intersect and users) separately. The output is the row IDs and distances of nearest neighbours. Some book-keeping will be required to guarantee you obtain the correct indices in the end (i.e., across the different levels of `label_street`).

Comment: Many thanks on your answer. How would you loop then? `split` by `label_street` and `ddply`?

Comment: Honestly, I would just use a for loop. Seems to be the most simple thing here, and I guess that you only itereate over few labels - very few in comparison to your very large data I guess? The advantage of the for loop is that you can rather easily select the correct rows from both of your data.frames in each iteration. But maybe other convenient options are available as well that I currently do not consider.

Comment: Or, you define a function that finds nearest neighbours, returning the correct IDs according to your column `ID` and then use `lapply`? Maybe that is better ...

Comment: There are possibly quite a large number of labels actually (in average `nrow(intersections)/2`). Also, what do you mean with the lapply solution? Not sure to get it right

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought it through entirely. I would try a for loop solution, but the efficiency may be seriously undermined if there are so many `street_labels` (but another kind of loop will probably not help much here). RANN is efficient because it can be applied to the whole data set but somewhat loses its point if you have to apply it to almost every other row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try though. Anyway, my solution is so slow that I'm in for any other solution

Comment: I just had an idea: How about you add a column with a very large value for each category (i.e., 1000 for label_street = 1, 2000 for label_street = 2 etc). Then you should be able to call `RANN::nn2` only onced on the entire data set (with the columns x, y, and the new column), while ensuring that neighbours are within the same label_street? Then no loop is needed at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses the `RANN` package to find nearest neighbours. The trick is to first ensure that elements with different `label_street` have a higher distance between them than elements within the same `label_street`. We do this by adding an additional numeric column with a very large value that is constant within the same `label_street` but different between different values of `label_street`. In total, you get:

```
intersections <- data.frame(x=c(0.147674, 0.235356, 0.095337, 0.147674), y=c(0.132956, 0.150813, 0.087345, 0.132956), label_street = c(5,6,5,6))
users <- data.frame(x = c(0.20428152, 0.17840619, 0.12964668, 0.20423856, 0.19349761, 0.10861251), y = c(0.14448448, 0.13921481, 0.11724543, 0.14447573, 0.14228827, 0.09891443), label_street = c(6,6,5,6,6,5), number = c(2703, 3460, 4325, 12506, 19753, 21282))

# add a numeric column that is constant within each category and has a very large value
intersections$label_street_large <- intersections$label_street * 1e6
users$label_street_large <- users$label_street * 1e6

# call the nearest neighbour function (k = 1 neighbour)
nearest_neighbours <- RANN::nn2(
  intersections[, c("x", "y", "label_street_large")],
  users[, c("x", "y", "label_street_large")],
  k = 1
)

# get original IDs and distances
IDs <- users$number[c(nearest_neighbours$nn.idx)]
distances <- c(nearest_neighbours$nn.dists)

IDs
# [1]  3460 12506  2703  3460  3460  4325
distances
# [1] 0.03171236 0.03136304 0.02391247 0.03175620 0.04271763 0.01760940
```

I hope this helps you. It should be very fast because it only call `nn2` once, which runs in O(N * log(N)) time.

Comment: Thanks! That seems great to me! I have one question about `RANN:nn2` though: what happens when either `query` or `data` is empty?
For instance, I might have a `street_label`appearing in `intersections`with no matching rows in `users`. I think one needs to add an exception for such a case, right?

Another point: don't we need to reverse the order of `intersections` and `users`here? I think that we should use `data=users` and `query=intersections` here, as we want the NN of each `intersection` row

Comment: Actually, it's pretty straightforward: we just need to remove from `intersections` those rows that have no matching in `users` and then perform your solution. It's extremely fast! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help =)